# DataBind From CodeBehind in a FormView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, code-behind, formview

I am trying to databind fields in a formview from the codebehind. If I were to do it in the front end, it would be something like:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtField" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("col_name") %>' />
```

and col_name would be present in the select and update commands of the sqlDataSource bound to the parent FormView that the textbox is in.

As the form is generated dynamically in the codebehind, I can't use the <%# Bind() %> syntax. How can I bind the textbox from the codebehind? If I can't, what is the best solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use Databinder.Eval in Code behind.

```
Me.txtRun.Text = DataBinder.Eval(ObjectOnPage, "PROPERTYNAME")
```

If you are doing this in the dgData_RowDataBound Gridview Method you can use e.Row.DataItem

```
Protected Sub dgData_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles dgData.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtControl"), TextBox).Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Property")
    End If
End Sub
```

More info can be found in the following link:

[DataBinder.Eval Method (Object, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will only enable one way communication (i.e. Eval() not Bind()), however as I have been googling for a long time and haven't found a better approach, I have concluded that what I want isn't possible. Going ahead I will ditch the sqlDataSource approach and just wire things up by hand in the codebehind.

Comment: Ah I see, I did't know you needed two way binding :) I also found a link with some info on the subject: http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx